# Property of double H

Tags: riddle, knowledge, cipher, pattern

- *It is the property of double H.*
- *It is a symbol of respect.*
- *It is attached to a moving thing.*

---

***Solve for the missing codeword to know the answer.***

| Number | Part 1 | Part 2 | Codeword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sawlog | Member | ALGEBR1 |
| 2 | Camper | Vigour | APRIOR2 |
| 3 | Uncalm | Earset |  |
| 4 | Maglev | Recoil | ALVEOL4 |
| 5 | Walnut | Sinful | ANTIFL5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the property of double H.

> Howard Hamlin’s license plate says NAMAST3

It is a symbol of respect.

> Namaste is a symbol of respect

It is attached to a moving thing.

> It’s a license plate on a car

To solve the codeword

> take the 2nd, 4th, and 6th letter of Part 1, concatenate the 2nd, 4th, and 6th letter of Part 2, and then concatenate the Number
>  U**n**c**a**l**m** E**a**r**s**e**t** **3** = **NAMAST3**